# Paging Oracle update query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a Update query

```
UPDATE tablename
set column1 = 'value1', column2= 'value2', column3= 'value3'
where column4 = 'value4
```

I need the statement above modified to do:

1. a commit every 5,000 records
2. stop after a total of 500,000 rows have been updated.

Is it possible in oracle11g? How can we achieve it?

Wrote a SQL procedure:

```
DECLARE
fromCount   number(10) := 0;
toCount     number(10) := 0;
BEGIN 
    LOOP
        toCount := fromCount + 5000;

      UPDATE tablename
    set column1 = 'value1', column2= 'value2', column3= 'value3'
    where column4 = 'value4 AND ROWNUM > fromCount AND ROWNUM < toCount;

        COMMIT;

        IF toCount=500000 THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

It is taking more than 1 hour to execute it. How can i improve the performance of it?

Comment: Use a stored procedure for it.

Comment: A statement is atomic, it must either completely succeed or completely fail.  It wouldn't make sense for a single SQL statement to commit every 5000 rows.  You could write some PL/SQL that iterated over the rows you want to update and included interim commits but that is almost always a mistake.  That slows down your process, it makes it more complicated, it requires you to do a lot of housekeeping to make the process restartable, etc.  Why would you want to do that rather than just letting Oracle update all the rows you want it to update in one shot?

Comment: What about LIMIT and OFFSET concept? Can we use that to achieve it? I don't know much about it

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` don't exist in 11g.  12c introduces an `OFFSET` and `FETCH FIRST | NEXT`.  I suppose you could use those in the PL/SQL to select the rows you want to update (though that would most likely overcomplicate the solution even more) but not in the `UPDATE` statement itself.

Comment: and moreover. why do you need it? definitely it is not for performance reasons because it will be slower. Are you trying to use some pattern from MySQL or MSSQL on Oracle? If you really insist on doing it like this you have to use PL/SQL and use   `UPDATE table_name
  SET set_clause
  WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name;`

Answer (score 0):

You may use 'and rownum <= 500000' condition. But the problem is, you won't know which records are updated and which are not.